# Sync the cache of multiple nginx servers

Tags: nginx

I have a master caching server with nginx. Its setup with proxy_pass and proxy_cache.
But I want to add more nginx caching servers in other locations that will all contain the same contents with master cache server. 
So it wouldnt matter to which server I send the request.
Is it possible to just rsync the cache directory across all the servers?

Comment: Not sure Nginx allows this. You might want to look into distributed caches -- something like varnish, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, since I don't actually know if it is ok to rsync cache directories (have you tried? what results you got?), but if you configured nginx correctly it shouldn't matter to which server you send requests, they'll fetch it from the cache if available and go to origin servers if not - that's the whole point of caching: they will self populate with use.

I wouldn't bother too much about initial seeding unless you have some very strange very specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of syncing the cache of multiple nginx servers you can always redirect particular type of request to corresponding nginx server by generating the hash key out of the request and assign those range of hash keys to particular servers.

If you are implementing this at scale where you have millions/thousands of request and latency in milliseconds matters a lot then you can implement the aforementioned approach by utilizing the consistent hashing as an approach.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing